# How to initialize vector of vector<char>?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I have data from sudoku puzzle. I have to define something below in `vector<vector<char>>`.

```
[[".", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"], 
 ["2", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
 ["3", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
 ["4", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
 ["5", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
 ["6", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
 ["7", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
 ["8", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
 ["9", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."]];
```

How to define above in vectors in cpp, tried below - didn't work.

```
char sudoku1[][] = [[".", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"],
                    ["2", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
                    ["3", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
                    ["4", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                    ["5", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                    ["6", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                    ["7", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                    ["8", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                    ["9", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."]];

    vector<vector<char>> sudoku2 =[[".", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"],
                                   ["2", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                                   ["3", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                                   ["4", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                                   ["5", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                                   ["6", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
                                   ["7", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                                   ["8", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
                                   ["9", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."]];

    vector<vector<char>> sudoku3 ={{".", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1" },
                                   {"2", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." },
                                   {"3", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." },
                                   {"4", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." },
                                   {"5", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." },
                                   {"6", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." },
                                   {"7", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." },
                                   {"8", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." },
                                   {"9", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }};
```

Comment: Post the code as text and not as images.

Comment: Please read on making a proper [MCVE]. Do _not_ use images for code, and _do_ include the compiler's error messages.

Comment: Changed the content to point out to code. Thankyou

Comment: for a start "." is not a char. '.' is a char

Comment: @AIR I changed the title because your question concerns with initialization more than definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For list initialization you should use braces (as `sudoku3` you showed). And note that `"."` is not a `char` (the supposed type of the element) but a `const` `char` array (i.e. `const char[2]`), so change `"` to `'`.

```
vector<vector<char>> sudoku4 = 
  {{'.', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1'}, 
   {'2', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
   {'3', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, 
   {'4', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
   {'5', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, 
   {'6', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, 
   {'7', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, 
   {'8', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, 
   {'9', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}};
```

Comment: One *could* use `{".87654321", "2........", ` and so on.  But that would be subtly different (the inner vectors would all have a trailing null character.

Comment: @MartinBonner I can't get what you mean. You can't use `".87654321"` to initialize the inner `vector`.